# Consolidating start of page

Tags: vertical-alignment

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298902/determine-the-height-of-a-box-with-a-rule).

I would like the contents of the page to start exactly where they would start if the header wasn't present. This turns out to be a lot more difficult than expected.

The following code works for small font sizes following the title:

```
\documentclass[twoside=false]{scrbook}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}%
\thispagestyle{plain}
\vspace*{-\dimexpr\topskip+\baselineskip+\parskip}
\parbox[b][0pt]{\textwidth}{
    {\Huge Test}\\[-1ex]
    \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth}{1mm}
}
\par
{\Large\vspace{\dimexpr\topskip-\baselineskip-\parskip}}

\Large test

\clearpage

test

\end{document}
```

However, using `\Huge` as font size for the following text, the height of the text outgrows `\topskip` (I think?), so my solution does not work any more.

Using environments that add vertical space does not seem to work either, since `\vspace` behaves differently when there is no text at the start of the page.

I have tried

```
\newcommand\vspacesave[1]{\vspace{#1}}
\renewcommand\vspace[1]{\vspace*{#1}}
\begin{flushleft}
    test
\end{flushleft}
\renewcommand\vspace[1]{\vspacesave{#1}}
```

but to no avail.

**Edit:** All of this seems to be in vain anyway, since trying to create space with `vspace*{...}` just gives me different amounts of space again...

Comment: if what you're inserting is only one line, you could `\smash` it and insert a `\strut` of the "usual" size to establish the baseline.  (not tested)

Comment: @barbarabeeton:Thanks. Although I am not quite sure how this magic trick works, it solved the `\vspace*` issue.

Answer (score 1):

if what you're inserting is only one line, you could `\smash` it and insert a `\strut` of the "usual" size to establish the baseline.

`\smash` gives the "smashed" material a zero height and depth. that would result in it being moved higher on the page, so you really need to reset the height to the "usual" value. that's what a `\strut` does.

`\strut also` resets the depth. in this case that doesn't matter, but there are situations where it does.